# C# NEST's serializing FieldValue & AggegateDictionary all nulls

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Good day:

I'm querying my Elastic instance and getting back results for both my `scriptField` and `Aggregation`:

**ScriptField**

```
"fields": {
          "distance": [
            6569.304614953225
          ]
        }
```

**Aggregations**

```
"aggregations": {
    "children#Capacity": {
      "doc_count": 15,
      "histogram#Capacity": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": 0,
            "doc_count": 15
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "geo_distance#Distance": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "*-5.0",
          "from": 0,
          "to": 5,
          "doc_count": 15
        },
        {
          "key": "6.0-105.0",
          "from": 6,
          "to": 105,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "106.0-505.0",
          "from": 106,
          "to": 505,
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The Elastic response gets mapped to `ISearchResponse` however serializing `ISearchResponse.Hits.Aggregations` and `ISearchResponse.Hits.Fields` into JSON, the values are all empty:

**Fields**

```
{ 
    "fields": {
    "distance": {}
    }
}
```

**Aggregations**

```
 {
    "Aggs": {
    "Capacity": {
    "Capacity": {
    "Items": [
      {}
    ],
    "DocCountErrorUpperBound": null,
    "SumOtherDocCount": null,
    "Meta": null,
    "DocCount": 0,
    "BgCount": 0
    }
    },
    "Distance": {
    "Items": [
      {},
      {},
      {}
    ],
    "DocCountErrorUpperBound": null,
    "SumOtherDocCount": null,
    "Meta": null,
    "DocCount": 0,
    "BgCount": 0
    }
    }
}
```

As you can see the `distance` in the `scriptField` response is empty. Also the `items` in the Aggregation is also empty.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregation response types only have deserialization implementations, not serialization implementations. [Check out the discussion in GitHub issue 3093](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3093).

If needing to reserialize to a JSON string, you can take one of two approaches

1. make the request with the low level client, using the high level search request type, and return a string response. Then, if needing a strongly typed response from the JSON string, perform the deserialization to `SearchResponse<T>` in the application

   ```
   // build your search request using NEST's request types
   var descriptor = new SearchDescriptor<Question>()
       .Query(q => q
           .Match(m => m
               .Field(f => f.Title)
               .Query("Elasticsearch Kibana")
           ) && +q
           .Term("type", "question")
       );

   var response = client.LowLevel.Search<StringResponse>("posts", PostData.Serializable(descriptor));

   // the JSON string response from Elasticsearch
   var jsonString = response.Body;

   ISearchResponse<Question> searchResponse = null;
   using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)))
       searchResponse = client.RequestResponseSerializer.Deserialize<SearchResponse<Question>>(stream);

   // do something with the documents
   var documents = searchResponse.Documents;
   ```

or

2. set `.DisableDirectStreaming()` in the request configuration for this request only, so that the response bytes are buffered on the `ISearchResponse<T>`. Then get the JSON string response from these bytes with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes);`

   ```
   var searchResponse = client.Search<Question>(s => s
       .Query(q => q
           .Match(m => m
               .Field(f => f.Title)
               .Query("Elasticsearch Kibana")
           ) && +q
           .Term("type", "question")
       )
       .RequestConfiguration(r => r
           // capture the request and response bytes for this call only
           .DisableDirectStreaming()
       )
   );

   // do something with the documents
   var documents = searchResponse.Documents;

   // the JSON string response from Elasticsearch
   var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(searchResponse.ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes);
   ```

Taking one of these approaches also means that the JSON string represents exactly what has come back from Elasticsearch.